# Angular 2. Http calls to an "api" subdomain

Tags: angular

The following example makes a regular call to http://example.com/api/products

```js
makeApiCall(): Observable<ICall> {
    return this.http.post<ICall>('/api/products', {}, {})
}
```

For architectural reason, I need to make calls on 'api' subdomain (http://api. example.com/products)

How would I construct a call in such cases?
Please note, I would not hardcode 'example.com' anywhere.

Comment: How would you intend to host the name of the domain `http://example.com`? without specifying the domain, the http call will be done to the base domain of the angular app

Comment: Basicaly, I want to append `api.` to the base domain whatever is.

Comment: but where does the api domain come from? how would the angular app know where to get it from?

Comment: It knows about 'BASE_URL'.

Comment: are you saying that the API url is the same as the angular url?

Comment: Let me explain. Why I need this? I build docker image that may be serving in test.com, stage.com, prod.com where I need calls to api.test.com api.stage.com, api.prod.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to add the base url i.E. `https://api.example.com` to the enviroment varables. If that's not an option you might can do it like this:

```js
const baseUrl = document.location.protocol + '//api.' + document.location.hostname;
return this.http.post<ICall>(baseUrl+'/api/products', {}, {})
```